# Generally Converting For Loops to List Comprehensions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to grasp the syntax of converting for loops to list comprehensions.

I understand the very basics, which would be:

```
[expression **for** item **in** list **if** conditional]
```

However, I have a for loop which stores a value in an intermediate variable. I'm newer to Python, so it may be sloppy coding on my part:

```
for n in wf:
    if n == 'Table of Contents':
        continue
    name = wf[n].iloc[1,2]
    store_list.append(name)
```

I'm not sure how I would store the `name` variable in a list comprehension. Do I need to store it? Is there a better way to code this?

```
store_list1=[]
store_list1 = [name = wf[n].iloc[1,2], store_list1.append(name) for n in wf if not == 'Table of Contents']
```

The code above returns a syntax error at the equal sign...Could someone explain to me if it is possible to code this particular for loop as a list comprehension? Thanks in advance,

Comment: is `wf` a dict? What will `n` be?

Comment: My apologies. wf is an excel workbook I read in as a dict object using `None` as the argument for sheet_name=... n returns a cell containing a string with a store's name.

Comment: alright, assuming `wf[n].iloc[1,2]` is valid, i think my answer gives you what you want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
store_list1 = [wf[n].iloc[1,2] for n in wf if n != 'Table of Contents']
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I think I see how saving to an intermediate variable and appending was redundant in my code. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

From context added in the comments, `wf` is a dict.  So don't look up the key twice - instead you want to iterate, in pairs, the *items* of `wf`:

```
store_list = [v.iloc[1,2] for k, v in wf.items() if k != 'Table of Contents']
```

Comment: This is also a great answer...I'm just really starting to try and learn list and dictionary comprehensions. Is there a good resource to study?